# OpenLayers: Utility getSource().on to wait one second to load or reload TileLayer

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I am using OpenLayers5.

I'm working with Tile Layers in my project, but I need that when I move to the map, the layer will load with one second delay to no call many times to server.

My code is

```
app.controller("MainController", [
  function () {
    const map = new ol.Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          id: "positions",
          visible: true,
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            refresh: {
              force: true,
            },
            visible: true,
            projections: ["EPSG:4326"],
            url: "http://localhost:9000/getMap",
          }),
        }),
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 0,
      }),
    });
  },
]);
```

I saw in OpenLayers the following three functions:

```
getSource().on("tileloadstart", function () {
   // While loading the layer
   console.log("tileloadstart");
});

getSource().on("tileloadend", function () {
   // At the end of the layer loading
   console.log("tileloadend");
});
      
getSource().on("tileloaderror", function () {
   //If throw error while loading
   console.log("tileloaderror");
});
```

I need to wait a second while I move the map or zoom so as not to overload the server calls

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more likely related to the TileWMS not being correctly specified.  It must have a `params` option specifying the WMS `LAYERS`, and `projection` should be singular.

A simple one second delay could be included in a tile load function

```
  tileLoadFunction: function (imageTile, src) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      imageTile.getImage().src = src;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

but that will **NOT** reduce totals calls to the server, it will simply delay all calls by the same interval, giving a very poor user experience, then you will get the same server problem one second later.

To reduce simultaneous calls to the server you should experiment with the map's `maxTilesLoading` option and if using TileWMS try using a larger tile size - a single call for a 512px tile is four calls when using 256px tiles.